# how to validate DropdownBelow in flutter

Tags: flutter, validation, dropdown

I'm using `DropdownBelow` instead `dropdownbutton` because i want to opent the dropdown diaglogue below the dropdown button, but there is no validation argument in its package and i want to add validation, can u please let me know how to do this. here is the code

```
onChangeDropdownTests(counterType) {
    print(_selectedCounterType);
    setState(() {
      _selectedCounterType = counterType;
    });
  }

 Container(
                      height: 55.0,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                      child: DropdownBelow(
                        itemWidth: 370,
                        itemTextstyle: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            color: Colors.black),
                        boxTextstyle: TextStyle(
                            //fontSize: 14,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            color: Colors.black),
                        boxPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(13, 12, 13, 12),
                        boxWidth: 370,
                        boxHeight: 50,
                        boxDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                            borderRadius:
                                new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(10.0)),
                            border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.grey)),
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_outlined,
                          color: HexColor("#6e6b7b"),
                        ),
                        hint: Text('Select counter type',
                            style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                                color: HexColor("#6e6b7b"), fontSize: 15)),
                        value: _selectedCounterType,
                        items: counterTypes
                            .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: value,
                              child: Text(value,
                                  style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                                    color: HexColor("#6e6b7b"),
                                  )));
                        }).toList(),
                        onChanged: onChangeDropdownTests,
                      )),
```

or is there any way how to open the dropdown dialogue below the dropdown button like this

[image]

using **FormField**

**update code:**

```
 FormField<bool>(
                              autovalidateMode:AutovalidateMode.always,
                              builder: (state) {
                            return Container(
                                height: 55.0,
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.82,
                                child: DropdownBelow(
                                  itemWidth: 350,
                                  itemTextstyle: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                      color: Colors.black),
                                  boxTextstyle: TextStyle(
                                      //fontSize: 14,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                      color: Colors.black),
                                  boxPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(13, 12, 13, 12),
                                  boxWidth: 370,
                                  boxHeight: 50,
                                  boxDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.transparent,
                                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
                                          new Radius.circular(10.0)),
                                      border: Border.all(
                                          width: 1, color: Colors.grey)),
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_outlined,
                                    color: HexColor("#6e6b7b"),
                                  ),
                                  hint: Text('Gender',
                                      style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                                          color: HexColor("#6e6b7b"),
                                          fontSize: 15)),
                                  value: _selectedGender,
                                  items: genderList.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                                      (String value) {
                                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                        value: value, child: Text(value,style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(color: HexColor("#6e6b7b"),)));
                                  }).toList(),
                                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    this._selectedGender = newValue.toString();
                                    
                                  });
                                },
                                ));
                                
                                },
                                validator: (value) {
                                if (this._selectedGender==null) {
                                  return 'You need to select gender';
                                } else {
                                  return null;
                                }
                              },
                                ),
```

Comment: You want to required dropdown?

Comment: yeah, but that dropdown dialogue should be same as which i uploaded image, and i want to add validation on it.

Answer (score 0):

To validate DropdownBelow you will need write a formfield for it. example: DropdownBelowFormField, when you extend from [FormField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormField-class.html) you will able to add validation.

Comment: please check my updated question, i uploaded code using ```FormField```, it is not working, can u please check where i'm doing wrong.